# Simplest way to spawn multiple Python instances in single SSH connection

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a project based on a Raspberry Pi running the latest release of Raspbian Jessie. 4 separate Python scripts (that contain infinite loops for the operation of multiple stepper motors, other hardware devices and polling of ADCs and input devices) run concurrently in 4 separate SSH connections and communicate data between each other via a simple UDP socket server.

Everything works perfectly at this point, however, it's not feasible to have 4 separate SSH connections to the machine. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to spawn 4 separate instances of Python that:

1. Aren't subject to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)
2. Are able to pass variables to and from one another

Currently the system is based on Python 2.7. I've experimented with Python 3 (for `asyncio`) to no avail. I have also, unsuccessfully, tried utilising the `multiprocessing` and `threading` modules.

I don't necessarily need another Python script to spawn all 4 instances; a shell script would be just fine. I understand that it may be possible using `os.subprocess(shell=True)` or something along those lines?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: This question feels a bit open-ended as this comes off as a design choice, to which there are many solutions. If I had to suggest, perhaps a single ssh which then proceeds to spawn 4 bash processes on the micro-controller to control the stepper motors?

Comment: Could you just write a shell script that calls those 4 functions in the background? i.e., from ssh call `bash ./caller.sh` which has 4 lines of `python2.7 script1.py & python2.7 script2.py & ...`?

Comment: Would the single shell script not just wait for the first script to exit? (Which will never happen).

Comment: It’s not a design choice at this point - it’s lacking the knowledge to implement!

Comment: @jeremysprofile How though, are independent Python processes, started like that, going to share variables?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Couldn't they still communicate through localhost sockets? Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: The comms between separate processes wouldn’t be the issue as they’re already using localhost sockets. I just assumed that a shell script like that would wait for the first Python instance to return before executing the second.

Comment: @AdamMitchell, `&` at the end of a line means put a process in the background, meaning the current line will be called and the script will immediately continue to the next line.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Ah, looks like that’s like the solution then; will have a go tomorrow and see how it works out. I assume that any writes to stdout are suppressed? It’s not an issue in this case; just curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this seems to be the solution:

You simply have one SSH connection to the machine that calls a single script:

```
ssh me@raspi "bash ~/caller.sh"
```

That script will call all of your functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
python script3.py &
python script4.py &
```

The `&` at the end of the line means that the command for that line will be run in the background and bash will not wait for that line to finish before starting the next one. The `&` on the last command is optional depending on whether you want to be returned to the command prompt immediately or not.

For your comment, writes to stdout are not suppressed; you will see output from all 4 python scripts intermingled based on how far through each script it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `bash` script starting 4 background jobs might work fine for PoC stage and testing. But if later on you would want to reliably run your code for longer than a few minutes you would need to implement some superviser logic. My advice is to use `systemd` to set up 1 controller and 4 worker services instead. This way `systemd` will do the heavy lifting of monitoring/restarting/etc your services and you will use `ssh` just to control the master service.